# What is the most effective way in systemVerilog to know how many words a string has?

Tags: system-verilog

I have Strings in the following structure:

cmd, addr, data, data, data, data, ……., \n

For example:
"write,A0001000,00000000, \n"

I have to know how many words the String has.

I know that I can go over the String and search for the number of commas, but is there more effective way to do it?

Comment: By "effective", do you mean "built-in" and/or "more concise"? Because, although I don't have any knowledge of Verilog, I'm willing to bet that counting the commas is one of the most efficient ways to count the words.

Answer (score 1):

UVM provides a facility to do regexp matching using the DPI, in case you're already using that. Have a look at the functions in uvm_svcmd_dpi.svh
Verilab also provides [svlib](http://www.verilab.com/resources/svlib/), a package containing string matching functions.

A simpler option would be to change the commas(,) to a space, then you can use `$sscanf` (or `$fscanf` to skip the intermediate string and read directly from a file), assuming each command has a maximum number of words.

```
int code; // returns the number of words read
string str,word[5];
code = $sscanf(str,"%s %s %s %s %s", word[0],word[1],word[2],word[3],word[4]);
```

You can use `%h` if you know a word is in hex and translate it directly to a numeric value instead of a string.

Comment: @dave_59- The problem that The size of the line (str) is dynamic.

Comment: That should not be a problem

Comment: @dave_59- why? what should I write instead of "word[5]", and I don't know how  many "%s"....

Comment: Is there a maximum number of words on the line? Plan for the max and `code` returns the actual number of word read.  If not, then you will need to resort to your original plan of searching for commas or using the DPI approach.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to define extremely clearly what a word actually is vis. what constitutes the start of a word and what constitutes the end of the word, once you understand this, if should become obvious how to parse the string correctly.

Comment: it doesm't important. All the words are seperated by commas.

Answer (score -1):

In Java StringTokenizer is the best way to find the count of words in a string.

```
String sampleString= "cmd addr data data data data...."
StringTokenizer st = new Tokenizer(sampleString);
st.countTokens();
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: The tags make it clear OP needs to solve their problem in SystemVerilog, not Java.

Answer (score -1):

In java you can use following code to count words in string

```
public class WordCounts{

   public static void main(String []args){

        String text="cmd, addr, data, data, data, data";
        String trimmed = text.trim();
        int words = trimmed.isEmpty() ? 0 : trimmed.split("\\s+").length;
        System.out.println(words);

   }
}
```

Comment: I don't need java.I asked about systemVerilog